Why has my ubuntu machine started turning off randomly?
I have been using a laptop as a home server for about 2 months. It is running docker with 6 containers, I primarily access it through ssh or portainer. For some reason about a week ago it started shutting itself off seemingly randomly, is there any way I can check why it is doing this, and any way to stop it?
Here is the result of running last -x | head | tac
runlevel (to lvl 5)   6.5.0-28-generic Fri May  3 23:03 - 23:11  (00:08)
moksh    pts/0        192.168.1.30     Fri May  3 23:04 - 23:07  (00:03)
moksh    pts/0        192.168.1.30     Fri May  3 23:07 - 23:11  (00:03)
moksh    pts/0        192.168.1.30     Fri May  3 23:11 - 23:11  (00:00)
shutdown system down  6.5.0-28-generic Fri May  3 23:11 - 23:12  (00:00)
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-28-generic Fri May  3 23:12   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   6.5.0-28-generic Fri May  3 23:12 - 14:14 (3+15:02)
reboot   system boot  6.5.0-28-generic Tue May  7 14:14   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   6.5.0-28-generic Tue May  7 14:14   still running
moksh    pts/0        192.168.1.30     Tue May  7 14:15    gone - no logout

And the result of using sudo journalctl -b -l -e shows the below
May 07 12:01:17 server kernel: asus_wmi: Unknown key code 0x6d
May 07 12:01:20 server systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-eced9a483e8492ade037097b767f2d7bea42327e64440010f13d57bb973411e2-runc.LfRpWw.mount: Deactivated successfully.
May 07 12:01:25 server systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-eced9a483e8492ade037097b767f2d7bea42327e64440010f13d57bb973411e2-runc.04kppZ.mount: Deactivated successfully

^ This is followed by several more run-docker-runtime Deactivated successfully messages.
I am using:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

Laptop Details:
ASUS ROG GL552VW-DH71
GPU GeForce GTX 960M 2GB VRAM
16GB DDR4
Intel i7 CPU


Have you found a solution to this issue? I have been suffering the same for a period of time already. Exact same usage as yours, same laptop, but with Debian. kernel: asus_wmi: Unknown key code 0x6d does not always lead to a system shutdown but it's always there before it does. It's been happening between 4am and 5am when in theory load should be minimal. I'll be tracking temperature, see if heating has something to do with it, like answer below mentions.

I reverted to an older version of cloudflare and that has been helping so far, I haven't done enough testing to confirm just yet.

I had the same problem (server kernel: asus_wmi: Unknown key code 0x6d, and then it shut down randomly.)
My laptop's lid was closed and it was overheating constantly, but since I opened the lid the problem has disappeared.
I understood the problem since laptop was shutting down only in high load.

This seems to be the most likely reason. I measured temps on my asus laptop with screen off and I see a spike on temps and fans speed around 10 to 20 minutes before the shutdown. Unfortunately the fans are not cooling it down enough so it eventually sends the shutdown trigger: kernel: asus_wmi: Unknown key code 0x6d. I'm now investigating what's causing such spike...
